# execution time sql query on java 8

Tags: java, sql, performance, java-8, java-6

I have java code that retrieves data from an oracle database with a simple query that runs in less than 1 second and it gets over 50,000 lines so this is not a problem in sql, but when i run the code:

- java 6 -> 2 seconds
- java 8 -> 16 seconds
  on java 8, when running there is no blocking but it takes time when loading **ArrayList**, I tried with **HashMap** => same problem

  ```
  String sql ="sql SELECT * FROM XX_Product_Sup WHERE XX_Product_Sup.AD_Client_ID IN (0,1000000)";
  PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
  ResultSet rs = null;        
  ArrayList<Object[]> result = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
  try {
      pstmt = DB.prepareStatement(sql, trx);
      pstmt.setMaxRows(startRow + rowCount);
      rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
      ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
      int rowNum = 0;
      while (rowNum < startRow && rs.next()) {
          ++rowNum;
      }
      while (rowNum < startRow + rowCount && rs.next()) {
          ArrayList<Object> row = new ArrayList<Object>();
          for (int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
              Object obj = rs.getObject(i);
              if (obj instanceof Number)
                  row.add(rs.getBigDecimal(i));
              else if (obj instanceof Date)
                  row.add(rs.getTimestamp(i));
              else
                  row.add(rs.getString(i));
          }
          result.add(row.toArray());
          ++rowNum;
      }
  } catch (SQLException e) {
      log.log(Level.SEVERE, logBuffer.toString());
      throw e;
  } finally {
      if (pstmt != null)
          pstmt.close();
      }
  return result.toArray(new Object[0][]);
  ```

I want to know more about the performance of collections & loops between Java 8 & 6

Comment: just a side note, but prefer using `try-with-resources`-statements, when handling resources

Comment: There shouldn't be much noticeable difference. If anything, I'd expect Java 8 to be slightly faster. You should profile it.

Comment: Which version of the JDBC driver JAR are you using, with Java 6 and with Java 8?

Comment: @LukeWoodward data extraction from oracle is done in 1 sec but the loading in ArrayList takes a lot of time

Comment: You seem to have assumed that all data is read into the `ResultSet` in one go.  This is simply not true.  Data will be read from the database into the result set as necessary.  The performance difference is undoubtedly due to a change in how Java talks to the database, which is why I asked for the version of the JDBC driver JAR you are using.  Besides, if you think there has been a catastrophic drop in performance in the  `ArrayList` class between Java 6 and Java 8, then try writing a class that demonstrates the problem without talking to a database.